# jQuery $.when with function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery with deferred objects:

So when I am using

```
$.when(
  $.ajax("test.aspx")
).done(function(){
  console.log('1');
});
```

Everything works fine. 1 is shown only after ajax is executed and returned. But if I will do

```
function a(){
  $.ajax("test.aspx")
}

$.when(
  a()
).done(function(){
  console.log('1');
});
```

everything breaks apart. Any idea how to fix it using function a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your function to return the ajax promise:

```
function a() {
  return $.ajax("test.aspx");
}
```